# Model AjaxControlToolkit popup closed when operation button Click in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox

I have AjaxControlToolkit popup Control in my asp.net project. While Clicking Submit, the popup window closed. but i have wrote code to validate form in C#,. How to stop the popup closeing.

Popup will be close button Clicking, otherwise popup not want to close.

**STYLE**

```
  <style type="text/css">
        .Background
        {
            background-color: Black;
            filter: alpha(opacity=90);
            opacity: 0.8;
        }
        .Popup
        {
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            border-width: 3px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: black;
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-left: 10px;
            width: 400px;
            height: 350px;
        }
        .lbl
        {
            font-size: 16px;
            font-style: italic;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
```

**ASPX CODE -**

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Fill Form in Popup" />
    <!-- ModalPopupExtender -->
    <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mp1" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panl1" TargetControlID="Button1" 
        CancelControlID="btnClose" BackgroundCssClass="Background">
    </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panl1" runat="server" CssClass="Popup" align="center" Style="display: none">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="lbl" Text="First Name"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Font-Size="14px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" Click="btnSubmit_Click" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" Click="btnClose_Click" /> <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br />      
    </asp:Panel>
    <!-- ModalPopupExtender -->
    </form>
```

**C# -**

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtName.Text != "")
        {
            lblError.Text = "Error";
        }
    }
```

**Output -**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Dont Go for C# Try JavaScript Validation Like This

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function ValidateControls() {

        if (document.getElementById('<%=txtName.ClientID %>').value == "") {


            alert('ERROR');
            return false;
        }


        else {
         alert('OK');
            return true;
        }

    }
</script>
```

//button code

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" Click="btnSubmit_Click" OnClientClick="return ValidateControls() />
```